# Calling Sleep in x86 Intel assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, intel

I've seen both uses. What is the difference? Why use one over the other?

```
call Sleep
call kernel32.Sleep
```

Comment: `call kernel32.Sleep` is not valid syntax. If it works for you, it's because of an assembler extension or an include file that does magic. Symbols are either global or local; there is no module-level scoping in assembler.

Comment: `kernel32.Sleep` and are this is compile and linking ?! how is `kernel32.Sleep` declared ?

Comment: I saw `call kernel32.Sleep` in the Memory Viewer in Cheat Engine. A x64 example is found in: [Screenshot](http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5675589&sid=6419e21ab496de24a99b880ec0a2e3a0)

Comment: im code example is `call Sleep`. `Memory Viewer in Cheat Engine` - this is not compiler. how debugger/disasembler or other displayed code - another question. in all case function need be declared somehow befor use it in compiler and for linking need use `kernel32.lib` where `__imp__Sleep@4` symbol for x86 Sleep

Comment: @CodyGray Why should this not be valid **syntax**? Most assemblers allow the period (.) as regular character. Of course the symbols `Sleep` and `kernel32.Sleep` **may** be different addresses...

Comment: @MartinRosenau it's not valid as long as you start with empty MASM code for windows, and just add the bare minimum required to use kernel32.dll API. Of course it is valid syntax, if you define some `kernel32 STRUC` or something like that, or some kind of macro, etc... but that's beyond the bare minimum which is needed normally.

Comment: @Ped7g The user has seen the code in an example; we don't know which assembler was used in the example. GNU assembler for example would allow defining some label `kernel32.Sleep:` followed by `jmp *__imp__Sleep@4` in one assembler file and calling this label using `call kernel32.Sleep` in another assembler file.